# How to remove borderColor of NativeBase TextArea?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am a creating a screen where a user can input any text without constraints.
I tried using **NativeBase** TextArea and it should work. But when pressed, the border changes color. My expected behavior is that the TextArea's borders should never display any color.

**Here is a screenshot of my screen:**

[image]

**Here is a code snippet in creating the textArea:**

```
<TextArea
          borderColor="transparent"
          h={'98%'}
          textAlignVertical="top"
          placeholder="| Add Notes"
 />
```

I tried changing borderColor to 'transparent' but it seems like it is not what I am looking for. That property only changes the borderColor when it is not active.

Maybe there is a way to remove validation of the textArea so that borderColor will not update? Or is there a more suitable property for this kind of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u try

```
borderWidth:0,
```

not sure if it can work tho

Comment: Perfect. Now I feel so dumb missing something so simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use prop borderWidth or borderColor or both

`import { TextArea } from 'native-base';`

```
<TextArea
   rowSpan={3}
   placeholder="Add Comment"
   borderWidth={0}
   borderColor='transparent'
/>
```